# Invalid JWT while using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Until Friday, I was using the JSON file from google cloud console to access locally my project (storage and firestore), no problems.

But today it stopped to work.

On my code, I have the following line accessing a Firestore document:

```py
reference = firestore.collection("forms").document(uid)
document = reference.get() // HERE the error ocurrs
```

Whenever I try to access the Google APIs I got the error:

> Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim

But I just generated the JSON file minutes before try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer. It was my system clock with wrong time